# Loop all the tables using whileloop

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop, database-cursor

I have a some set of 4 tables policy table, coverage table, vehicle table and driver tables.

Policy table example

| policy number | record lauyout |
| --- | --- |
| Abc | polr |
| Efg | polr |

Coverage table example

| Policy number | record layout |
| --- | --- |
| Abc | prop |
| Abc |  |
| Efg | prop |

Vehicle table example

| Policy number | record layout | vin number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abc | prp1 | 123 |
| Abc | prp1 | 123 |
| Efg | Prp1 | 456 |

Driver table example

| Policy number | record layout | vin number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abc | subj | 123 |
| Abc | subj | 123 |
| Efg | subj | 456 |

I need to fetch first policy record then associated coverage then associated vehicle record then associated driver record. I have to loop all the tables and  need to write the logic using SQL whileloop. Please give me some guidelines to achieve this one.

**Desired output:**

| Policy Number | Record Layout | VIn number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abc | polr | null |
| Abc | prop | null |
| Abc | prp1 | 123 |
| Abc | subj | 123 |
| Abc | subj | 123 |
| Efg | polr | null |
| Efg | prop | null |
| Efg | prp1 | 456 |
| Efg | subj | 456 |

Comment: Seems unlikely you need a loop, set based operations should solve your issue

Comment: It looks like you just need to `UNION` all of the tables together, adding a fixed `null as [vin number]` to the select list for the first two tables, and finishing out teh query with an `ORDER BY`.  Not sure where the "subj" values are coming from. Perhaps you intended those to be part of the sample Drivers data.

Comment: So do you want to loop through the combined query results then? Perhaps you can show us what you have tried so far to help us understand your intentions.

Comment: Hello friends,any suggestions on my requirement.please provide me some advice thanks

Comment: Desired output I have already written in the question,table structure given

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loops, a simple `union all` query with an additional, hard-coded value for the purpose of sorting the results will give you your desired results:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT [Policy Number], [Record Layout], NULL as [VIn number], 1 As [Table Order]
    FROM Policy
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT [Policy Number], [Record Layout], NULL, 2
    FROM Coverage 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT [Policy Number], [Record Layout], [VIn number], 3
    FROM vehicle 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT [Policy Number], [Record Layout], [VIn number], 4
    FROM Driver 
)

SELECT [Policy Number], [Record Layout], [VIn number]
FROM CTE
ORDER BY [Policy Number], [Table Order]
```